# excel copy row to another sheet based on cell value

Tags: vba, macros

I want to copy the rows based on cell value (**Emp_Section**;  `Emp_Section` containts **Front**) from **Sheet1** to **Sheet2**.

I have the following script which will copy all the rows

```
Sub EmpCopy()
    Dim myCols As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'   Set columns you want to loop through in an array
    myCols = Array("D", "B", "C", "F")

'   Loop through columns array
    For c = LBound(myCols) To UBound(myCols)
'   Find last row in column W with data
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, myCols(c)).End(xlUp).Row
'       Copy data from Model sheet to summary sheet
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, myCols(c)), Cells(lastRow, myCols(c))).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, c + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next c
     Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

Screenshot attached.

Is anyone willing to explain to me what I need to do

[image]

Comment: *what I need to do* Do not look at the code - it won't help you. Create your own code from the beginning.

Comment: ok. I tried to write the code from the beginning. Being a beginner, I am not able to interchange the column(```as shown in Sheet2```).

Comment: Use 2 arrays. First - copy source range into it. Second - use it for assigning values in proper order. After all elements in 1st array processed assign 2nd array to destination range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as a template:

```vba
dim src() 'for source data'
dim tmp() 'for temporary data'
dim dst() 'for destination data'

src=sheets("source").range("Xm:Yn").value 'get source data'
redim tmp(ubound(scr,1),4)                'destination have 4 columns'
n=lbound(tmp,1)

for i = lbound(src,1) to ubound(src,1) 'process source row by row'
    if src(i,5) = 'Front' then         'if marker found, store data in temp array'
        tmp(n,1) = src(i,4)            '4th source column to 1st dest column'
        tmp(n,2) = src(i,2)
        tmp(n,3) = src(i,3)
        tmp(n,4) = src(i,6)
        n=n+1                          'increase found rows count'
    end if
next i

redim dst(n-1, 4)    'for found rows only'

for i = lbound(dst,1) to n-1 'reassing temp to dest, skip excess elements'
    dst(i,1) = tmp(i,1)
    dst(i,2) = tmp(i,2)
    dst(i,3) = tmp(i,3)
    dst(i,4) = tmp(i,4)
next i

sheets("destination").range("Xm:Yn").value = dst 'store processed data'
```

Debug the code carefully - the template may contain some misprints or errors.